# Считивание из файла

Tags: c#, файлы, data-structures

```
public class Student     //клас Студент надо считать дание из файла
    {
        public string surname;
        public string name;
        public int[] date = new int[3];        // день месяц год
        public int[] marks = new int[3];         //3 оценки
        public Student next;

        public Student(string s, string n, int[] dArray, int[] mArray)
        {
            date = dArray;
            surname = s;
            name = n;
            marks = mArray;
            next = null;
        }

    }
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Student> obj;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            obj = new List<Student>();

        }
 private void fromFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string readpath = @"C:\Users\andri\Desktop\textin.txt";
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(readpath))
                {
                          //как правильно считать из файла если между даними будет пробел???
                    string line = " ";
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string currentSurname;
                        string currentName;
                        int[] currentDate = new int[3];
                        int[] currentMarks = new int[3];
                        currentSurname = sr.ReadLine();
                        currentName = sr.ReadLine();

                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                        {
                            currentDate[i] = sr.Read();
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                        {
                            currentMarks[i] = sr.Read();
                        }obj.Add(new Student(currentSurname, currentName, currentDate, currentMarks));
                        sr.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `split()` в помощ

Comment: спасибо за помощь